# Way to make custom arrow in Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to add an arrow to my plot in matplotlib, but I dislike the beveled look of the arrow. Is there any way to get an arrow with a more triangular tip? I haven't been able to find anything in the documentation or elsewhere. Here is my current code

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.annotate('',
            xy=(0.5, 0.9),  # End point of the arrow
            xytext=(0.5, 0.55),  # Start point of the arrow
            arrowprops={'arrowstyle': '<|-|>', 'color': 'darkgoldenrod'}, xycoords='axes fraction',
            textcoords='axes fraction')
plt.text(0.55, 0.725, r"$\times$20", color='darkgoldenrod', fontsize=7, ha='left', va='center', transform=plt.gca().transAxes)
```

I've tried all of the different `arrowstyle` options provided by matplotlib as well as playing around with some other parameters, but no matter what all of the arrows still have a bevel to them.

Comment: What bevel are you referring to? What do you want the arrow to look like?

Comment: The edges of the arrow are rounded in any of the arrowstyles that matplotlib provides, I want sharp edges on my arrow.

Comment: Can you add a zoomed-in photo pointing out what you don't want? Maybe also a photo of what you do want.

Comment: Edge of the arrow are not in any way rounded on my PC. It is a very plain, boring, triangle (well, as sharp a triangle can be, when it uses only a few pixels)